# How can I turn this string into a datetime?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date string that looks like this:

`Mon Jun 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

and I want to insert into a mysql `datetime` column like this `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i`. I tried using php `DateTime`, but it gives me an error because there are two time zones. I can't change the returned string because it's the return value for a function in an api I'm using. How can I get this to the right format?

Comment: Have you tried using `strtotime()`?

Comment: Do you want to store date with `timezone` in database?

Comment: I've used string to time, but it gives me this: 1969-12-31 19:00. Also, I don't need timezone, I am going to fix everything in db to use one time zone (or maybe unix time) to keep things straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try this:

```
$string = 'Mon Jun 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)';
$string =  preg_replace('/\(.*\)/', '', $string);// remove (Eastern Daylight Time)
echo date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($string));
```

Would print out:

'2016-06-20 00:00'

Hope this helps.

Comment: It actually prints out as 1969-12-31 19:00 , I tried the same eariler and couldn't figure out why .. Actually, that is with the whole string (including the eastern daylight at the end) so I guess that must be the problem, I'll have to format the string to get rid of it first .

Comment: @NickCabrera Yes, you need to get red of the text first as it's not a valid format. I have done that by using `preg_replace`. Feel free to mark this as an answer if it solves your problem. Cheers

Comment: Thank you! It's been driving me crazy.